# How do I import/update (eg cost price) in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I am using Odoo v8 in Combination with Magento. I imported all products from Magento to Odoo, now I would like to mass update multiple fields on the products in Odoo based on the Internal Reference field:
 - Cost Price
 - Supplier
 - Inventory Levels
 - Weight
 - Status
 - Leadtime

What is the best way to do that? Can I use the import CSV function for that or do I have to do that directly via the database?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update a lot of data, I suggest use CSV file, it reduces write much code more than use XML file to insert/update/etc... data in data base, and in my personal opinion insert/update/etc... the data manually it's not the best practice.

For example to insert `country state` in data base:

By CSV file:

`id country_id:id   name    code
state_us_1  us  Alabama AL
state_us_2  us  Alaska  AK
state_us_3  us  Arizona AZ
state_us_4  us  Arkansas    AR
state_us_5  us  California  CA
state_us_6  us  Colorado    CO
state_us_7  us  Connecticut CT
state_us_8  us  Delaware    DE`

By XML file:

```
<record model="res.country.state" id="state_us_1">
    <field name="name">Alabam</field>
    <field name="code">AL</field>
    <field name="country_id" ref="base.us"/>
</record>

<record model="res.country.state" id="state_us_2">
    <field name="name">Alaska</field>
    <field name="code">AK</field>
    <field name="country_id" ref="base.us"/>
</record>
```

One record for every data!

I hope this can help you!